# Make the whole div clickable instead of the links inside of it

Tags: html, css, click

So i'm making some grids to show products in and  would like to make the whole div tag clickable instead of just the hyperlinks inside of it.

What would be the best and easiest way to do this. I found some complicated solutions which i rather not use since i have a lot of these divs i want to make clickable.

Any suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: Here is an example of a block i would like to make clickable: http://jsfiddle.net/Lookinggoodtoday/eBeZ3/

Comment: I think your best option is to use Javascript like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eBeZ3/1/).

Comment: Use JavaScript to set `click` events on the objects?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. If possible i would prefer to do it without Javascript since i know nothing about it at all. But if it's really needed in this case i will go for it.

Comment: What? You can do that with just HTML!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what complicated examples you're talking about but you will need to use something like jQuery:

Give the div a class:

```
<div class="myBox">
     blah blah blah.
    <a href="http://google.com">link</a>
</div>
```

and in page load, hook up the handler with a selector:

```
$(".myBox").click(function(){
     window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
     return false;
});
```

See http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-entire-div-clickable/

Answer (score 1):

You can make the whole div clickable instead of just content inside it. Just put like this :

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><div id="mydiv"> Blah Blah </div></a>
```

That's it.
Here is JS Fiddle : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RfT47/2/)

Comment: @Harry It was assumed that it is a part of grid. So there must be a parent div nesting this <a> as well as <div> inside it. Moreover , you can change the inline property via css. And , I don't see a reason why it isn't appropriate to do so? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I guess you missed that *Edit* that I added to the comment. Originally as per HTML specs block elements inside inline were not good practice but as per HTML5 it seems OK. I left that comment as-is only for you to be able to see the Edit. I will remove it now :)

Comment: It is part of a grid. I made an update of the fiddle including the rest of the grid. Now going to try and apply Abhinav's method.  http://jsfiddle.net/Lookinggoodtoday/eBeZ3/2/

Comment: If that's your code , why are you using <a> and not applying a 'href' attribute to it o_O. that's not a good way to use classes , if you want them , use them with div and spans.

Comment: Beginner here:) If i apply 'href' to the <a> tag only the image inside the div will become clickable. I want the whole div to be clickable including the white area and the price tag within the border.

Comment: 'href' tag dosen't changes anything except pointing to the next web address you want your users to go on clicking that link. Wait , I'll make your fiddle according to my example.

Comment: Do you have the url of that fiddle? Thanks.